# How to calculate count by group, then keep only one per group

Tags: r, merge, data.table, aggregate

Say that I have this data.frame, `data`:

```
data <- data.frame(val=c(rep(6,10), rep(7, 15), rep(8, 20), rep(9, 25), rep(10, 100), rep(11, 20), rep(12, 15), rep(13, 10)))
data$plus <- data$val + 100
```

My goal is to create a new `data.frame` that has the frequencies of each `val`, and the associated `plus` value.

My current strategy is to create a table (called `table`), then merge the frequencies. Then to keep only the first observation within each group:

```
table <- table(data$val)
df1 <- data.frame(val = as.integer(names(table)[1:length(table)]), N = table[1:length(table)])
df2 <- merge(data, df1)
df3 <- do.call(rbind, by(df2, list(df2$val), FUN=function(x) head(x, 1)))
```

This works, but it seems clunky.

In Stata, for example, it would be less and simpler code. Something like:

```
bys val plus: egen max = _N
bys val plus: gen first = _n==1
keep if first==1
```

Is there a way to simplify or make more elegant the R code?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's an approach using "data.table":

```
library(data.table)
as.data.table(data)[, N := .N, by = val][, .SD[1], by = val]
#    val plus   N
# 1:   6  106  10
# 2:   7  107  15
# 3:   8  108  20
# 4:   9  109  25
# 5:  10  110 100
# 6:  11  111  20
# 7:  12  112  15
# 8:  13  113  10

## Or (@RicardoSaporta)
as.data.table(data)[, list(.N, plus=plus[1]), by = val]

## Or (@DavidArenburg)
unique(as.data.table(data)[, N := .N, by = val], by = "val")
```

With "dplyr", you can try:

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  group_by(val) %>%
  mutate(N = n()) %>%
  slice(1)
```

In base R, I guess you can try something like:

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(data, data$val), 
                      function(x) cbind(x, N = nrow(x))[1, ]))
```

Comment: If your data is large, the following will be a bit swifter (although the code a bit more cumbersome):  `as.data.table(data)[, list(.N, plus=plus[1]), by = val]`

Comment: Or `unique(as.data.table(data)[, N := .N, by = val],  by = "val")`

Comment: Or `data %>% group_by(val, plus) %>% summarise(N = n())`

Comment: @StevenBeaupré, I don't want to assume that this data really represents the OP's data.... (in other words, I don't want to assume that they have a bunch of repeated values for each "var").

Comment: I thought OP wanted to have frequencies (group size) for (val, plus), no ?

Comment: @StevenBeaupré, Honestly, I don't really read Stata code. I just assumed since they were calculating N just by using `table` on one variable, it's related to that one variable.

Comment: @AnandaMahto That's a fair assumption. It's not clear to me either.

Comment: I think it's worth noting that the very convenient `by` argument in `unique` is not available in `base::unique`, it's actually `data.table:::unique.data.table`

Answer (score 3):

**Edited**

Or you can use `aggregate()`

```
data$N = 0
out = aggregate(N ~ val + plus, data = data, length)
```

or else

```
out = aggregate(plus ~val, data = data,function(x) c(unique(x), N = length(x)))
do.call(data.frame, out)
```

or using `ddply`

```
library(plyr)
out = ddply(data, .(val,plus), summarize, N = length(plus))

#> out
#  val plus   N
#1   6  106  10
#2   7  107  15
#3   8  108  20
#4   9  109  25
#5  10  110 100
#6  11  111  20
#7  12  112  15
#8  13  113  10
```

Comment: ... and be wary that you have a matrix as your new "column".

Comment: The problem with your update is that it depends on "plus" having only one (repeated) value for each "val". That's the case with the example, but I doubt it's the case with the OP's original data. An easier solution is to take your original solution and wrap it in a `do.call(data.frame, yourOriginalCode)`.

Comment: yeah, you are right if the original data isn't the same. I have added your suggestion in the answer